# Как реализовать многократное нажатие на элемент?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как в зависимости от числа нажать кнопку программно столько же раз, сколько это число, на jquery:

```
switch(click) {
    case 1:
      $('.slick-prev').trigger('click');/*нажать один раз*/
      break;
    case 2:
      $('.slick-prev').trigger('click');/*нажать 2 раза*/
      break;
    case 3:
      $('.slick-prev').trigger('click');/*нажать 3 раза*/
      break;
    case 4:
      $('.slick-prev').trigger('click');/*нажать 4 раза*/
      break;
    }
```

Comment: что ты понимаешь под _нажать 2 раза_ и т.д.?

Comment: А зачем жать на стрелку `slick-slider`, если можно использовать его методы типа `slickGoTo` или `slickNext` ?

Comment: А как их использовать и где подключать?

Comment: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/  Смотрите "Methods"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по классам, автор использует `slick-slider` и преследует цель прокрутки к определённому слайду при клике на кнопку. Вот пример с использованием методов `slick-slider`:

```js
$('.slider').slick();
$('.go-btn').click(function(){
  var slideIndex = $('.slide-number').val() - 1;
  $('.slider').slick('slickGoTo', slideIndex, false);
})
```

```css
.slider{
  margin:0 0 30px;
}
.slide{
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#cda;
  font-size:40px;
  line-height:2;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
  <div class="slide">4</div>
  <div class="slide">5</div>
  <div class="slide">6</div>
</div>
<button class="go-btn">go to</button>
<input class="slide-number" type="number" min="1" max="6" step="1" value="1" />
```

Comment: хороший ответ. Что-то редко стали отвечать, всегда с интересом читаю ваши ответы.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT , спасибо. Работы много, не всегда хватает времени на SO

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, можно обойтись без конструкции `switch`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < click; i++) {
    $('.slick-prev').trigger('click');
}
```

где `click` - то число, которое Вы хотели написать в `switch`.

По хорошему, сюда бы еще ограничение поставить, чтоб не ушло в "бесконечное кликание", но это уже на Ваше усмотрение.

**UPDATE**: в соответствии с комментарием OP, привожу вариант решения для "последовательных" нажатий.

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    $('.slick-prev').trigger('click');
});
```

В этом случае сколько бы угодно раз Вы не нажимали на кнопку с установленным `id="btn"`, на каждый клик по кнопке, будет вызван клик по `.slick-prev`.

Comment: Вы не поняли вопрос. Нажать на кнопку нужно не один раз, click раз последовательно!

Comment: @ArturHan, ты пробовал запускать этот код?

Comment: @ArturHan, как Вы сформулировали, так мы и поняли. Судя по голосам "за", есть еще люди, которые считают, что приведенный пример кода отвечает на вопрос: "как в зависимости от некоторого N, нажать на кнопку N раз".

Comment: @ArturHan, я обновил ответ и добавил пример для "последовательных" нажатий.

Comment: Неет,нужно чтобы при одном нажатии на кнопку, элемент нажимался несколько раз! Вы что думаете я бы писал здесь вопрос, если все было так просто! Тогда бы никакой особенный код и ненужен!

Comment: @ArturHan, а почему ты думаешь что он не нажимался несколько раз? :-)

Comment: @ArturHan, тогда объясните подробнее, что вы имеете ввиду. Лично я вижу противоречие в Ваших же комментариях: *"Нажать на кнопку нужно **не один** раз"* и *"Неет,нужно чтобы **при одном нажатии** на кнопку"*, что в свою очередь сбивает с толку